# Python delete in a string

Tags: python

I have these 3 strings:

> YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T21fdsfdsfs
>   YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,Tdsfs
>   YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,TD

I would like to remove everything after the last `,` including the comma. So i want to remove these parts `,T21fdsfdsfs`, `,Tdsfs` and `TD`. How could i do that in Python?

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Create a new string with the pieces you want to keep.

```
','.join(s.split(',')[:4])
```

Comment: You can also use -1 instead of 4 if you just want to remove the last part and do not know how many parts there will be.

Comment: -1 because Cristian really has the right idea IMO. I've done the equivalent in my own code many times.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: I think that Ignacio assumed that only the first 4 fields are needed (and the rest are garbage), but only [hssss](http://stackoverflow.com/users/530988/hssss) can really clear things up.

Answer (score 5):

```
s.rsplit(',', 1)[0]
```

Anyway, I suggest having a look at [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357499/python-delete-in-a-string/4357503#4357503) too, it might make more sense for your problem.

Comment: If there will be a variable amount of commas then this is the solution that doesn't break. A modification of Ignacio's answer has that feature as well but this one still creates less intermediate strings.

Answer (score 3):

According to [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

...so here's a third, which uses [`rpartition`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition):

```
>>> for item in catalogue:
...     print item.rpartition(',')[0]
... 
YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT
YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT
YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT
```

I haven't compared its performance against the previous two answers.

Comment: `python -m timeit -n 20000000 '"YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T21fdsfdsfs".rpartition(",")[0]'` gives *0.301 usec per loop* and `python -m timeit -v -n 20000000 '"YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T21fdsfdsfs".rsplit(",", 1)[0]'` gives *0.489 usec per loop*. I'm using python-2.7-8.fc14.1.x86_64 on Core 2 Duo E6400.

Comment: Neat! I see similar results, too. Thanks.

Comment: For completeness, `python -m timeit -v -n 20000000 '",".join("YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T21fdsfdsfs".split(",")[:4])'` yields: *1.19 usec per loop*.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to `string` elements, you can utilize
[`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to separate each string, setting `maxsplit` to 1.

> `str.rsplit([sep[, maxsplit]])`
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done, the rightmost ones. If sep is not specified or None, any whitespace string is a separator. Except for splitting from the right, rsplit() behaves like split() which is described in detail below.

```
>>> lst = "YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T"
>>> lst.rsplit(',',1)[0]
'YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT'
>>>
```