# python ............. delete

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python delete in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357499/python-delete-in-a-string)

I have the following list which has 3 elements:

YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T

YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T

YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,CHILD,F

I would like to remove everything after the last comma.. Note that I could have more than one character after the last comma. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: @hssss: You just duplicated a question you yourself asked (and received good answers for) less than 30 minutes ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357499/python-delete-in-a-string

Comment: +1 that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @sukhbir.  You may be right.  Never the less... `bad questions beget bad answers` (see below for confirmation)

Comment: @sukbbir (I just noted your [deleted] answer).  That is/was the only correct answer, if we assume that this 2nd question of hssss is about deleting part of each of strings elements in an a list.

Comment: mjv, hehe I realize now after reading the last line 'more than one character'. But anyways since the question is closed, doesn't really matter :)

Answer (score 3):

If you name your string s it would be:

```
s = s[:s.rfind(",")+ 1]
```

remove the one if don't want the comma at the end.

Comment: typo: "+ 1" should be inside the braces;... s[:s.rfind(",")+1]

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to `string` elements, you can utilize
[`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to separate each string, setting `maxsplit` to 1.

> `str.rsplit([sep[, maxsplit]])`
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done, the rightmost ones. If sep is not specified or None, any whitespace string is a separator. Except for splitting from the right, rsplit() behaves like split() which is described in detail below.

```
>>> lst = "YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T"
>>> lst.rsplit(',',1)[0]
'YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [84]: s = 'YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,Tkj'

In [85]: re.search('(.*,)(.*)$', s).groups()
Out[85]: ('YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,', 'Tkj')
In [86]: (a, b) = re.search('(.*,)(.*)$', s).groups()
```

`a` will contain the part you want and `b` will contain the part you want to delete