# Delete results of a grep search across files

Tags: python

I have a script which ultimately should grep a chunk of a text from a file and delete it, then repeat this for every file in a directory. But the code I've written below does not include the delete statement because I'm not sure how to do that. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357499/python-delete-in-a-string) makes me think I should instead grep everything I want to keep and write that to a new file instead. I tried inserting `del p` after the `p = re.compile(ur'(.)(\D\D\D\D\D..........)')` line and that seemed to delete one of my input files. Suggestions?

```
import sys
import re 
import os


PSGDirectory = "~/TestFolder"

  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(PSGDirectory):
    print path
    print dirs
    print files

  def process (files):
    p = re.compile(ur'(.)(\D\D\D\D\D..........)')
    return re.search(p, files)

  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PSGDirectory):
    for filename in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root,filename)
        print process (fullpath)
```

Comment: When you say "grep a chunk of text from a file and then delete it" what do you mean by "it"? Do you mean the text? The line _containing_ the text? The _file_ containing the text?

Comment: The text gripped probably

Comment: So.. if there is a file with `1234567`, and you grep `456`, then you want the file to end up as `123789`?

Comment: You could get all the strings that matched and replace them with empty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use re.sub()

From the [Docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
import os
import re

def process(file):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        text = f.read()
        # Use your regex to grab all matching text:
        # For example, to remove all non-digits from a string:
        filtered = re.sub(r'\D', "", text)
        f.write(filtered)
        return filtered

def main():
    PSGDirectory = "~/TestFolder"
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(PSGDirectory):
        print path
        print dirs
        print files
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PSGDirectory):
        for filename in files:
            fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            print process(full path)
```

Comment: local variable `f` is assigned but never used. Is that on purpose?

Comment: that looks great, except that nothing happens to my input files when I run the code. :0/ I'm trying to troubleshoot things now...

Comment: Apparently re.sub requires a string and when I read through my input file I think I have more than a string. I have a mixed bag, something like a tuple. Here is the error message I receive: `File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer`